# Django Static files not found - Site works but not pulling through static files - 404 console message

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am receiving a 404 for my static files, pages load but when inspect the console it relays the following errors, i've been sratching my head for while on this one. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction, it would be massively appreciated!:

```
127.0.0.1/:10 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/all.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:12 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:14 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:16 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/lightbox.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:26 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:28 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/lightbox.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:27 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:29 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:28 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/lightbox.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:29 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here's some of the code from the settings.py file:

```
DEBUG = True
```

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

```
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/btre/static/')
]
```

Here's the base.html file:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
  <!-- Custom -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  <!-- Lightbox -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/lightbox.min.css' %}">
  
  <title>BT Real Estate</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/lightbox.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[This is my directory/file path to the static folder containing the CCS, JS, IMAGES etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If4oP.png)

Here's my temrinal output when i ran collect static:

```
(venv) computer_name:btre_project user.name$ python manage.py collectstatic

132 static files copied to '/Users/user.name/dev/btre_project/static'.
```

[Here's an image of the collected static folders after being copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7x0p.png)

Comment: Did you add static url to main urls.py? Like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `STATICFILES_DIRS` not `STATICFILES_DIR`

finally do a `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it for me! Much appreciated!

Comment: glad i could help